# jQuery plugin accept array as an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating my first jQuery plugin.

```
var defaults = {
    breakpoint: {
        width: 1920,
        target: "",
        place: "after"
    }
}
```

Here is my default options. I would like to accept several breakpoints. Something like Slick carousel responsive: option.

```
$( "a" ).move({
    breakpoint: {
        width: 1800,
        target: "p",
        place: "after"
    },
    breakpoint: {
        width: 1500,
        target: "p",
        place: "after"
    }
});
```

When I try to do this, I get only last one breakpoint information(that one with 1500 width).

How can I correctly declare my defaults array to accept as many arrays of values as user wants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if breakpoints is an array it should be formatted as:

```
var defaults = {
    breakpoints: [
        {
            width: 1920,
            target: "",
            place: "after"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

I'm creating my first jQuery plugin.

var defaults = {
    breakpoints: {
        width: 1920,
        target: "",
        place: "after"
    }
}
Here is my default options. I would like to accept several breakpoints. Something like Slick carousel responsive: option.

```
$( "a" ).move({
    breakpoint: [
        {
            width: 1800,
            target: "p",
            place: "after"
        },
        {
            width: 1500,
            target: "p",
            place: "after"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use array of breakpoints would be a better solution instead of giving single object

```
$( "a" ).move({
    breakpoints: [{
        width: 1800,
        target: "p",
        place: "after"
    }, {
        width: 1500,
        target: "p",
        place: "after"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your time. @godmode answer is a little bit more informative, so I'm going to choose it as an accepted answer.